# Need more auto-connection points on Visio shapes

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I am Visio 2013 user. How can I add more auto-connection points on shapes in Visio.
For example, a circle shape originally has 8 auto-connection points, but I need 8 points more totally 16 connection points around it.

P.S. From the Visio Options window, I checked "Show more shape handlers on hover" tick box to no avail.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

On the **Home tab**, in the **Tools** section, you should have a '**Connection Point**' command (`shift+control+1`). **Select** your shape, click the command, then **hold down the control key and left click** where you want to add, move, or delete a connection point.

[image: Visio connection points]

Comment: Thank you; That was helpful. Unfortunately my reputation is not enough to vote your answer up.

Comment: Oh holy cow! Now I want all those hours fighting with connection points back.

Comment: Best superuser question/answer!

Answer (score 20):

I found the point and click method for adding new connection points to be a bit clumsy so I prefer: ***Right click on shape -> Show ShapeSheet***. You can then edit the ***Connection Points*** table directly and ensure that your connectors are exactly where you want them.

In the image, the bottom two rows are two more connection points on a Square.
Those were added by right-clicking the last row, selecting ***Insert Row After***. Then set columns ***X*** and ***Y*** to the desired position. The other columns should automatically fill.
[image: Connection Points Table]

---

For those who can't find the **Show ShapeSheet** option: since Visio 2010 you have to enable developer functionality through the **Custimize Ribbon** option to use the ShapeSheet. More info: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-happened-to-the-ShapeSheet-18505403-6934-438d-b40e-ec32c89a979a.

Answer (score 0):

I see it's not working in visio 2013. What I did is converted shape to process and I got four connection points which worked for me.

Comment: I use Microsoft Visio 2013 Professional and Troy's answer is working fine.