# Connect Shapes in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

Im using Visio, thinking it should be most powerful diagram software and yet it cant simply connect a line like I want. Below is the situation I have. I want to connect line2 to Block2 just like line1, from the left side, I can't, I tried dragging the mouse from every point but it simply can't connect. Even ms paint could do in 2 mins...

I'm new to Visio, shouldn't be so hard though, I would be glad for your tips!

[image]

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/727839/need-more-auto-connection-points-on-visio-shapes

Comment: @JimG. My problem is not connection points, my problem is connecting Line2 just like Line1, identically. I manage to connect it but I dont want a straight line, I would like it to have edges just like Line1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is interesting because I tried to do it too in my Visio 2013 and it is not possible. The lines just don't want to connect like this. The problem is the default connection points on the shape. Do not use the **Connection Points** available on the shape, but make your own Connection Points (<kbd>Shift+Ctrl+1</kbd> then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on shape) and then connect the shapes with lines through these new connection points.

The lines might overlap with the shape or other lines. Click on the line to select it (dots on the line will appear) and move it till you bring it in the wanted shape. That should do the trick.

Here is the result:

[image: connection points make your own]

Comment: I see that you beautifully connected them but I cant :( can you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: First add your own connection points to the shape (I added 2 to the Block1 and 2 to the Block2), look here how to add connection points: https://superuser.com/questions/727839/need-more-auto-connection-points-on-visio-shapes

Comment: Now connect the shapes. The lines might overlap but don't worry. Now select the line (click on it) and you will see a small dot on the line. Hover with your mouse above it and your mouse will change shape, now drag the line so that it doesn't overlap with the other line.

Comment: @Anarkie can you do it now ?

Comment: before I was also adding my connection points but when I tried to move the lines from their dots to seperate and relocate I failed, now it somehow works, Im surprised, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Open the Connectors stencil, there are various shaped connectors there, try the one called Side to Side 2.